# apt-get update => could not open dpkg lock file (5: Input/output error)

Tags: apt

If I run "sudo apt-get update" I get following error messages

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (5: Input/output error)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

here a similar [aks-ubuntu:unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process)  was solved by deleting the lock file (after checking that the problem was not caused by another process "locking" the lock file)

I checked that no other process is having a lock and tried to remove the lock file which gives me

```
osmc@osmc:/var/lib/dpkg$ sudo rm lock
rm: cannot remove 'lock': Input/output error
```

also I tried to list all files and permissions:

```
osmc@osmc:/var/lib/dpkg$ ls -la
ls: cannot access available: Input/output error
ls: cannot access lock: Input/output error
ls: cannot access diversions: Input/output error
ls: cannot access info: Input/output error
ls: cannot access updates: Input/output error
total 680
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root   4096 May 25 17:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root   4096 May 23 23:46 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 May 23 23:48 alternatives
-?????????  ? ?    ?         ?            ? available
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      8 May 19 20:25 cmethopt
-?????????  ? ?    ?         ?            ? diversions
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    943 May 19 20:31 diversions-old
d?????????  ? ?    ?         ?            ? info
-?????????  ? ?    ?         ?            ? lock
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Apr 15 10:23 parts
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     65 May 19 20:29 statoverride
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      0 May 19 20:24 statoverride-old
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 330290 May 25 17:13 status
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 330290 May 25 17:13 status-old
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 May 23 23:48 triggers
d?????????  ? ?    ?         ?            ? updates
```

I thought that maybe the files with question marks are [not executable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243999/why-do-question-mark-characters-appear-when-changing-the-permissions-of-director) so I tried to make all files in dpkg executable:

```
osmc@osmc:/var/lib$ sudo chmod -R a+rX dpkg
chmod: cannot access 'dpkg/available': Input/output error
chmod: cannot access 'dpkg/lock': Input/output error
chmod: cannot access 'dpkg/diversions': Input/output error
chmod: cannot access 'dpkg/info': Input/output error
chmod: cannot access 'dpkg/alternatives/rcp': Input/output error
chmod: cannot access 'dpkg/alternatives/mt': Input/output error
chmod: cannot access 'dpkg/alternatives/editor': Input/output error
chmod: cannot access 'dpkg/alternatives/w': Input/output error
chmod: cannot access 'dpkg/alternatives/awk': Input/output error
chmod: cannot access 'dpkg/alternatives/rsh': Input/output error
chmod: cannot access 'dpkg/alternatives/pico': Input/output error
chmod: cannot access 'dpkg/alternatives/lzma': Input/output error
chmod: cannot access 'dpkg/alternatives/builtins.7.gz': Input/output error
chmod: cannot access 'dpkg/alternatives/pager': Input/output error
chmod: cannot access 'dpkg/updates': Input/output error
```

I also created a test file in that directory to test if there is a general problem of writing to the disk. It worked however...

dmesg gives

```
  osmc@osmc:~$ dmesg | tail -n 30
[  313.069081] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): ext4_iget:3921: inode #136661: comm gmain: bad extra_isize (23520 != 256)
[  317.069236] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): ext4_iget:3921: inode #136661: comm gmain: bad extra_isize (23520 != 256)
[  317.921020] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): ext4_iget:3921: inode #130830: comm kodi.bin: bad extra_isize (52864 != 256)
[  321.068403] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): ext4_iget:3921: inode #136661: comm gmain: bad extra_isize (23520 != 256)
[  325.069286] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): ext4_iget:3921: inode #136661: comm gmain: bad extra_isize (23520 != 256)
[  329.069371] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): ext4_iget:3921: inode #136661: comm gmain: bad extra_isize (23520 != 256)
.... (further similar errors)
```

Any ideas how to resolve the problem?

System: OSMC on a Raspberry Pi with an SD card

Comment: It looks like your SD card is dying... What does `dmesg | tail -n 30` output?

Comment: updated my question with dmesg output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you shut the system down, write down or copy the output of:

```
cat /proc/version
```

You then need to shutdown properly, take that SD card out and run `e2fsck` on all the ext4 partitions -- I am not sure if OSMC uses more than one, but you can check with `fdisk`.  You can cross your fingers while you are doing this because it is not a guaranteed fix.

With regard to why it happened, you may want to [investigate this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/31391/5538).  The info you got from `/proc/version` should tell you whether you are using a kernel built with one of the affected gcc versions.

Comment: As I understand you I should check the SD card with another computer? Currently I have only one Ubuntu set up in a Windows VM... Couldn't I do e2fsck on reboot like [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3289/checking-sdcard-for-errors-unmount-problem)?

Comment: If you really can't access the SD card with the VM then you could try that, but you will not necessarily be making life easier for yourself.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to run e2fsck from a live version and it fixed a lot of errors. Apt-get update works now